# Laravel multiple product images upload

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, upload

I have relations for colors and images,

each product have colors, each color have images and icon

this is the response from the database:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "1",
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "stocks_id": 1,
                "color_name": "Red",
                "icon": "111.png",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "url": "111-111.png"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "stocks_id": 2,
                "color_name": "green",
                "icon": "222.png",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "url": "111-111.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

**How can I create an HTML form to add this information?**

**and how to post these images which are grouped by colors with controller?**

Comment: Use like this in your form field `$array_name['colors']['color_name']`

Comment: @A.ANoman can u answer with a full example please?

Comment: Please share your html form at least what you want...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="id"/>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="colors[id][]"/>
<input type="text" name="colors[stocks_id][]"/>
<input type="text" name="colors[color_name][]"/>
<input type="text" name="colors[icon][]"/>
<input type="text" name="colors[images][$n+1][]"/>
```

In Controller

```
$colors= [];
$index= 0;
// colors[id] = [0=>1, 1=>2];
// colors[stocks_id] = [0=>234, 1=>289];

foreach($request['colors'] as $key => $color){ 

    if(!isset($colors[$index])){
       $colors[] = [];
    }

    if(!isset($colors[$index][$key])){
       $colors[$index][$key] = $color[$index];
    }

    $index++;
}
```

There should be one loop for iterating over colors and there will be another loop to iterate over all images regarding to that color.

Comment: what about the controller? how to do the loops?

Comment: I have updated the Answer, you can now check the controller code.